# Is it possible to create a list of buttons with a list of commands Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
filebuttons=[]
fileframe=Frame(main,height=1080)
fileframe.pack(side="right",fill="both")

file_label=Label(fileframe, text="File Selected: ",font=('Times New Roman',24))

filecommands=[]
for file in get_files():
    def temp():
        file_label.config(bg="green",text=str("File Selected: "+file))
    filecommands.append(temp)
    filebuttons.append(Button(fileframe,activebackground="green",text=file, width=300))

for n in range(0,len(filebuttons)):
    print(file)
    filebuttons[n].config(command=filecommands[n])

for button in filebuttons:
    button.pack(side="top")
```

This chunk of code is designed to sift through a list of buttons and add commands to them setting a label with the names from a list of files. however, it simply adds the final name to all the commands of all buttons meaning they all set the label to the text of the last file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the 'temp' function uses whatever the *current* value of 'file' is, not the value that it was when you added it to the list. This is known as "late binding". To get around this you need to make a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), which bakes the value of 'file' into the function. The easiest way to do that is to use the `functools.partial` function:

```
from functools import partial

for file in get_files():
    closure = partial(file_label.config, bg="green", text=str("File Selected: "+file))
    button = Button(fileframe,activebackground="green",text=file, width=300, command=closure)
    button.pack(side="top")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works perfectly. couldn't ask for a better answer :).